# Error: No default account store is mapped to the specified application

Tags: node.js, express, stormpath, express-stormpath

I followed the documentation here: https://github.com/stormpath/express-stormpath

Error: No default account store is mapped to the specified application

I get the above error in the console when I try to run my app. Is this more than likely a problem with my code, or should I go to my admin page on the Stormpath site?

I used windows command setx to set the environment variables, not sure if I need to do that if I have the api key and secret in my app.js file. I removed sensitive info with XXXXXXXX for this question.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//Stormpath
var stormpath = require('express-stormpath');

//Init Stormpath
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {

    apiKey: {id:'XXXXXXXXXX', secret: 'XXXXXXXXXX'},
    secretKey: 'random_string_of_words_go_here',
    application: 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/accounts/XXXXXXXXX'

}));

//home:
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('home');
    console.log(req.session);
});

app.get('/create-quiz', stormpath.loginRequired, function(req, res){
    res.render('createQuiz');
});


//404 page:
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.status(404);
    res.render('404');
});

//500 page:
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500);
    res.render('500');
});

app.on('stormpath.ready', function () {
    console.log('Stormpath ready...')
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express started on http://localhost: ' + app.get('port') + '; Press ctrl-C to terminate.')
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep! This error is most likely because of your Stormpath application configuration in the admin console.

Every application needs a "directory" to store your accounts, and it seems like you might not have one.

Try signing into Stormpath and adding a "directory" to store your accounts in the admin console. If you do, try making sure you check "default account location".

Here's what mine looks like. Hope this helps!

[image: stormpath applications page]

(Source: I work at Stormpath)

Comment: Thanks Edward! It turns out my directory was ok. It started working after I used "set" instead of "setx" for my apikey id, secret, and application href. Thank you for taking the time to read my question and providing insight into the directory, which helped me confirm that was in order.

Comment: Cool! Just curious, where did you get the following code from:

```app.use(stormpath.init(app, {

    apiKey: {id:'XXXXXXXXXX', secret: 'XXXXXXXXXX'},
    secretKey: 'random_string_of_words_go_here',
    application: 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/accounts/XXXXXXXXX'

}));```

I think the way you configured express-stormpath is incorrect, then. Although it might be from a old blog post / documentation?

Comment: Looks like the docs say to wrap the application in an object (which is probably why it couldn't find the "account stores" for the application)

http://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/configuration.html#inline-options

Comment: Hi Edward, I looked back and couldn't find exactly where I got that from, but I did wrap the application in an object as you specified and it is working great. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: No problem. Also confused about the secretKey parameter... Anyways environment variables are usually recommended, since they won't be in your git history as well as being easy to change around -- but either way works! =]